# What is the meaning of this asterisk? Python Pandas 100 question trying. str.contaubs

Tags: python, pandas

I am really new to python. I have to use python for my research class, so I WAS learning pandas by using resource of Pandas Data Science 100 questions.

I was working on a question that

"P-015: From dataset(df_cutomer), retrieve data in （status_cd）which starts from A-F, and end by 1-9. Displays the first 10 of the data. "

### The answer says

### df_customer.query("status_cd.str.contains(r'^[A-F].*[1-9]$')",
engine='python').head(10)

I know the . is connecting two arguments, but was not sure what * means in this.
The question is translated from Japan, and I am pretty new to python. It might really dumb question, but please answer for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at an online regex visualizer

[image]

[https://regexper.com/#'%5E%5BA-F%5D.*%5B1-9%5D%24'](https://regexper.com/#%27%5E%5BA-F%5D.*%5B1-9%5D%24%27)

Customer must start with A to F and ***have anything*** in between the last character of 1 to 9.

In particular, .* just means "0 or more of any character".